# Any idea of solving an optimization problem with cubic constraints?

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, linear-programming, global-optimization

I have the following optimization problem with cubic constraints, which is hard to solve. Are there any ideas, or related references, of solving such a problem?

$$ \begin{array}{ll} \underset {y, z} {\text{minimize}} & C \\ \text{subject to} & \frac{5+y}{2} \leq C, \\ & 1+\frac{2+y}{z\cdot y}\leq C \\& \frac{1}{z}\leq y \leq 1, \\ & 2\leq z\leq 3. \end{array} $$

In this optimization problem, $y$ and $z$ are the decision variables in the real line. And $C$ can also be considered as a decision variable. The first constraint can be transformed into $5-2C+y \leq 0$, and the second constraint can be transformed into $zy-Czy+y+2\leq 0$. Hence the second constraint can be seen as a cubic constraint, as it contains the term '$Czy$'. I would like to know are there any systematic ways of deriving the analytical solution of this optimization problem?

Comment: seems a standard case for Lagrange factors

Comment: @Erik The system becomes somewhat easier if you set $x=yz$ and express everything in terms of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: [Have you tried WolframAlpha?](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Minimize%5B%7Bc%2C%285%2By%29%2F2%3C%3Dc%26%261%2B%282%2By%29%2F%28z*y%29%3C%3Dc%26%261%2Fz%3C%3Dy%3C%3D1%26%262%3C%3Dz%3C%3D3%7D%2C%7Bc%2Cy%2Cz%7D%5D)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're actually trying to solve

min f(y,w)
s.t.
w <= y <= 1
2 <= 1/w <= 3  .... i.e., 2w <= 1 <= 3w. or 1/3 <= w <= 1/2

Here I replaced w = 1/z to make the bounds linear.

Two ways to go about solving this:

1. Plug this type of formulation into scipy (or some nonlinear solver) that uses some form of gradient descent.  This will get you to a stationary point that might be optimal.
2. Reformulate this as a qcqp and plug it into gurobi to solve.   In this case, you need to add variables to make this have only quadratic terms showing up.

Here is a sequence of transformations to make it a QCQP

$$
\begin{array}{cl}
\underset{y, z}{\operatorname{minimize}} & C \\
\text { subject to } & \frac{5+y}{2} \leq C, \\
& 1+\frac{2+y}{z \cdot y} \leq C \\
& \frac{1}{z} \leq y \leq 1, \\
& 2 \leq z \leq 3
\end{array}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{cl}
\underset{y, z}{\operatorname{minimize}} & C \\
\text { subject to } & \frac{5+y}{2} \leq C, \\
& 2+y \leq (C -1)(yz)\\
& 1\leq yz \leq z, \\
& 2 \leq z \leq 3
\end{array}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{cl}
\underset{y, z}{\operatorname{minimize}} & C \\
\text { subject to } & \frac{5+y}{2} \leq C, \\
& 2+y \leq (C -1)w\\
& 1\leq w \leq z, \\
& 2 \leq z \leq 3\\
& w = yz
\end{array}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{cl}
\underset{y, z,w,q,C}{\operatorname{minimize}} & C \\
\text { subject to } & \frac{5+y}{2} \leq C, \\
& 2+y \leq q\\
& 1\leq z \leq z, \\
& 2 \leq z \leq 3\\
& w = yz\\
& q = (C-1)w
\end{array}
$$

Here is some code to solve it:
from gurobipy import Model, GRB, QuadExpr

## Create a new model

m = Model("nonconvex_qp")

## Create variables

y = m.addVar(lb=1/3, name="y")
z = m.addVar(lb=2, ub=3, name="z")  # bounds on z are 2 and 3
w = m.addVar(lb=1, name="w")
q = m.addVar(lb=0, name="q")
C = m.addVar(lb=2.5, name="C")

## Set objective

m.setObjective(C, GRB.MINIMIZE)

## Add constraint: 5 + y <= 2C

m.addConstr(5 + y <= 2 * C, "c0")

## Add constraint: 2 + y <= q

m.addConstr(2 + y <= q, "c1")

## Add constraint: w <= z

m.addConstr(z <= z, "c2")

## Add constraint: w = yz

m.addConstr(w - y * z == 0, "c3")

## Add constraint: q = (C - 1)w

m.addConstr(q - (C - 1) * w == 0, "c4")

## Set the NonConvex parameter to 2 to allow Gurobi to solve nonconvex problems

m.params.NonConvex = 2

## Optimize model

m.optimize()

for v in m.getVars():
print('%s %g' % (v.varName, v.x))

The optimal solution is
y 0.47481
z 3
w 1.42443
q 2.47481
C 2.7374

Note: this is up to a tolerance of 10^-4.

If I crank it up a little, we get

y 0.4748096336
z 3.0000000000
w 1.4244289009
q 2.4748096336
C 2.7374048168

But I suppose that this means that z reaches it's upper bound of 3, so you can probably plug this into the original problem and try to obtain an analytical answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It seems the minimum is where these two curves meet.

So... ask Wolfram to solve
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%285%2By%29%2F2+%3D%3D+1+%2B+%282%2By%29%2F%283*y%29

Yields 2 solutions:
y = -7/6 - sqrt(97)/6
y = sqrt(97)/6 - 7/6

But only the second one is positive, so that must be the right answer.